# How to publish nodes 3 times a day?

Tags: views, nodes, rules

I have a list of unpublished nodes, created with the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module. I would like a task to be run 3 times a day, at specified times. Every time the task  runs, only one of the nodes on the list should be published. How can I do this?

### Steps I have tried

#### Scheduler

The [Scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler) module requires you to specify the exact time you want the node to be published. This makes it complicated, as I would have to work out when each node is supposed to be published.

#### Views Bulk Operations + Rules + Rules Scheduler

With the [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module, you can create a list of Nodes that are exposed to the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module. Rules can then act on the list and publish the node on the list. You can tell Rules to only publish a specific number of nodes.

This works perfectly. Except, it doesn't seem possible to schedule the Rule to run 3 times a day.

You can link the Rule to the main site Cron job, but this doesn't seem very precise as the Cron job could run more than 3 times.

There is a Rules Scheduler module (a sub-module of Rules), but it doesn't look like you can use this a Rules condition. There also doesn't seem to be a way to specify the running time.

#### [Job Scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/job_scheduler)

This lets you set a time, but it doesn't seem to integrate with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) or [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

Comment: Any reason you don't want to do this through a custom module? I can provide you an answer if you want to do it this way.

Comment: @Topsitemakers I was hoping to use an existing module, as it  will have been passed through more users so will be better code than mine!. I'm under the impression that what I want to do is possible, I just need to get the task scheduling bit sorted!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Using modules VBO, Rules and Rules Scheduler

About your approach using modules [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations), [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and Rules scheduler (submodule of [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)), for which you wrote "*it doesn't seem possible to schedule the Rule to run 3 times a day.*": that appears to me "a" valid approach.

What you actually need to do is a minor variation of what is explained in the tutorial [Hourly tasks using rules scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/node/1068136): in your case you should use an offset of 8 hours (instead of just 1).

And as explained also in that tutorial: *Initially execute the component manually.* (from then on every other 8 hours the rule will be executed again).

## Using modules Rules and Rules Once per Day

There is a fairly new module related to rules, i.e. the "[Rules Once per Day](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_onceperday)" module. Here is how it works (as per the [comment in issue 2495775](https://www.drupal.org/node/2495775#comment-9979169), from the module owner):

- You specify a **trigger hour** on the administration settings page for this module.
- The Rule trigger will then **run when cron tasks are first run after the start of that hour**. The actual run time will depend on your cron task timings.

The way I understand/Read this (haven't experimented with it yet though) is like so:

- The "Event" will only be triggered when a cron job is run.
- And that event will only be triggered 1 time / day, i.e. "next time cron runs after the trigger hour has passed".

So by creating 3 similar rules, you could have 1 of them run around (say) 6 pm, another one around 2 pm and the ast one at 10 pm.

PS: I'm assuming this question is about D7.

Comment: How do I get it to run at one time. There doesn't seem to be an option to activate a rule at a certain time.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Rules Once a Day module? Refer to my updated answer ... curious to hear if that culd work ...

Comment: "Rules Once a Day" only runs once a day. But I am hoping I could add an offset to get the times I want. Rules allows you to use `stringtotime()`. If "rules once per a day" ran at midnight and I wanted my rule to run at 6pm, would `+18 hours` be the correct way to write the `stringtotime` command?

Comment: True that Rules Once a Day only runs once a day (as its name also indicates). But if you define 3 (similar) rules, you then have 3 times once a day, right? Also, the actual trigger will be when your cron job runs. Say cron runs every hour, also on 6:05 pm (18:05). Then your "trigger hour" should be a little bit before that (like +18 hours), so that when the next cron runs (at 18:05), you get the trigger. If your cron also runs at (eg) 12:05 and 04:05, you should have another rule with trigger hour like +12 hours and yet another one like +4 hours.

Comment: Although I've only 90% tested this, it's the answer that has worked the best so far, so it gets the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Configuring cron jobs using the cron command](https://www.drupal.org/node/23714) at specified times you like.
2. Create a module to implement hook_cron(). To update your first node as `$node->status = 1`.

   $node->status = 0, means unpublished.
   $node->status = 1, means published.

   ```
   function yourmodule_cron() {
     update $node->status = 1;    
   }
   ```
3. You may use views_get_view() get your node nid

   ```
   $view = views_get_view('your_views_name');

   $view->execute('default');

   $view->preview();

   $renderer = $view->style_plugin->row_plugin;

   foreach ($view->result as $index => $row) {

     // get node NID from first row    

   }
   ```

Comment: How do I target the unpublished nodes? Thanks!

Comment: Use views_get_view() to get your node NID

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using some coding.

1. A view that lists all the nodes that are published for scheduling. If you also apply [DraggableViews](https://www.drupal.org/project/draggableviews) you can let administrators reorder the nodes by drag-and-drop, which is always nice.
2. A custom PHP function `publishdaily_get_top_node()` that executes the view above and returns the NID for the top node. I would recommend putting this in a custom mini-module.
3. A rule that is triggered on cron run, and checks whether it is time to publish a new node (by, say, checking if the time is between 00.00 and 00.15 – depending on how often your cron runs). If it is time, then it fires action 'load node' and uses `publishdaily_get_top_node()` to get the NID to load. Then it publishes the loaded node.

If you want to make it even more clean, you write a Rules plugin instead of just a PHP function.

If you want it less clean, you write the function directly in an action for executing arbitrary PHP code.

#### Reference

- [This answer](https://groups.drupal.org/node/93229#comment-295764) for [Scheduled Auto Publishing of group of Nodes in time intervals?](https://groups.drupal.org/node/93229)

Comment: `checking if the time is between 00.00 and 00.15` How would you check the time in rules? Thanks.

Comment: you can use a rule scheduler or job scheduler

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! If you are going to copy-paste an answer, please link the original post back.

Answer (score 0):

Create a rule as follows:

At /admin/config/workflow/rules/components/add

Create a "Action set":
        Name = Unpublish Content
        Variables:
                Data type = Node
                Label = Node
                Machine name = node
                -Continue-

```
    Add Actions:
      Node > Unpublish content
      Data selector = node
      -Save-
```

At /admin/config/workflow/rules
        Create a "rule":
                Name = Unpublish Rule
                React on event = Node > After saving new content
                Restrict by type = your content-type
                -Save-

```
    Conditions:
              Content is published
            Data selector = node
              -Save-

    Actions:
      Schedule component evaluation
      Component Value = Unpublish Content
      Scheduled evaluation date data selector = node:field-your-node-date-field
      Identifier value = Unpublish content ID [node:nid] ([node:title]).
      Node Data selector = node
      -Save-
```

That is, it is not necessary to filter the content when create the component nor add a content-type condition in the rule.

Additionally, check your website cron setting from Admin >> Configuration >> System >> Cron (admin/config/system/cron)

Let me know if you face any query/concern regarding this.

Comment: Thanks! How do I specify the times when the rule should run? (I only want it to run at specific times). How do I get it to publish only one of the nodes in my Views list of unpublished nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use a rule or code to publish a single node from the top of your view, I believe the easiest way to schedule it is to use [Ultimate Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron).

Set the scheduler to Crontab and for the specific task you can tell it *exactly* when you want it to run.  For instance if you want 8am, 12 noon and 4pm you can make the rule:

```
0 8,12,16 * * *
```

---

Further Information:

[Elysia Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) appears to allow for custom cron tasks, which may allow you to target a specific rule (perhaps via php code).

Comment: with  Ultimate Cron is it possible to trigger a rule. I tried playing with it, but couldn't figure it out. Rules doesn't seem to be able to respond to specific cron jobs (it reacts to all of them).

Comment: I didn't think so but it looks like [Elysia Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) might allow you to create custom jobs.